# how to run ROS across multiple machines with different networks?

Tags: ros, multiplemachines

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all,

Would I know how to run ROS across multiple machines with different networks? I failed to ping them like this:

PING 192.168.1.103 (192.168.1.103) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.217.252.54 icmp_seq=1 Time to live exceeded
From 10.217.252.54 icmp_seq=2 Time to live exceeded
From 10.217.252.54 icmp_seq=3 Time to live exceeded
From 10.217.252.54 icmp_seq=4 Time to live exceeded
From 10.217.252.54 icmp_seq=5 Time to live exceeded
From 10.217.252.54 icmp_seq=6 Time to live exceeded
From 10.217.252.54 icmp_seq=7 Time to live exceeded
From 10.217.252.54 icmp_seq=8 Time to live exceeded
^C
--- 192.168.1.103 ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 0 received, +8 errors, 100% packet loss, time 7011ms

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10101/how-to-run-ros-across-multiple-machines-with-different-networks?/) by [Nutan](https://answers.ros.org/users/170/nutan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2011-05-29

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on 2011-06-04**:
could you explain your network topology more? How is everything connected? As long as you're not able to ping across machines, you won't be able to get communication up and running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How are you connecting your two machines? Your first step is to have them able to communicate together. From your PING log they are on two separate subnets. You need to have routes setup
between the networks for that to work. Both of these subnets you have are both used for internal communication and will not be routed over the internet.

For information on using ROS on multiple machine I have found the following pages to be useful:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables

---

Originally posted by [Hordur](https://answers.ros.org/users/418/hordur/) with karma: 544 on 2011-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nutan](https://answers.ros.org/users/170/nutan/) on 2011-06-05**:
Hordur, tank you very much. I could ping from computer A to computer B, but could not ping from computer B to computer A. Thus, only computer A could be the master, but i want to take computer B as the master. Do I need to use openVPN?